# Prevent page-breaks while escaping curly braces and functions

Tags: page-breaking

I am having difficulties preventing a block of code from page-breaks.
Here is my example code:

```
\begin{samepage}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2pt}
{\bfseries \fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont TEST}\\
\vspace{1em}


{\bfseries TEST}\\
\begin {itemize}
  \item ABC
\end{samepage}
  \item XYZ
\end{itemize}
```

The idea here is to be able to have the title and one element of the list always on the same page, to avoid confusion.

I have tried this with \vbox{% ... } as well but it did not work.
The errors outputted are:

```
l.xxx \end{samepage}
?
```

or

```
extra } or forgotten
```

I'm using XeLaTex with TexWorks editor if it matters.

Thank you

Comment: `\begin{samepage}...\begin{itemize}...\end{samepage}...\end{itemize}` is not properly nested.

Comment: I'll try that. i had no idea that it needs to be nested.

Comment: also remove the `\\ ` they will be making badness 10000 warnings, which is as bad as TeX ever reports.

Comment: @gernot I tried nesting it but it still does not work. It only works like this: \begin{samepage}
  \begin {itemize}
    \item
\end{itemize}
\end{samepage}

Comment: @AlexanderCeed -- that's what is meant by "nesting": `a b endb enda` .  so i think this problem is solved.

Comment: @gernot -- would you like to write an (explicit!) answer?  or is this best closed as solved in comments?

Comment: @barbarabeeton But I really need to use samepage in the middle of a list. I only need to have the first element of a list on the same page, not the entire list.

Comment: @AlexanderCeed -- then try putting `\begin{samepage}` right before the first `\item`; not tested, and not guaranteed, but logically consistent.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX sectioning commands prevent a page break before a list, so if you use a standard markup such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\section*{Test}


A rule to move the heading close to the bottom

\rule{.5cm}{15.0cm}% test heading and two items
%\rule{.5cm}{15.1cm}% test heading and first item
%\rule{.5cm}{15.6cm}% test heading and first item
%\rule{.5cm}{15.7cm}% heading on second page

\subsection*{test}
\begin {itemize}
  \item ABC
  \item XYZ
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

then you can see by increasing the rule length that latex will break before the heading or after the first item, or after the list, but not between the list and the heading. No extra markup in the document is required.

[image]